# Prevent access to checkout without shipping method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I am trying to remove the proceed to checkout button and restrict access to the checkout page until a customer fills out the 'Calculate shipping' option on the basket page.

I created a local shipping method that's restricted to multiple post/zipcodes. I then went and added this to my functions.php file.

```
function disable_checkout_button_no_shipping() {
  $package_counts = array();

  // get shipping packages and their rate counts
  $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
  foreach( $packages as $key => $pkg )
      $package_counts[ $key ] = count( $pkg[ 'rates' ] );

  // remove button if any packages are missing shipping options
  if( in_array( 0, $package_counts ) )
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'disable_checkout_button_no_shipping', 1 );
```

However when I test the site in different browsers and in incognito modes the 'Proceed to checkout' button is there.

If I click on the 'Calculate shipping' link and not fill out the form but update it the button disappears. I basically want the button to appear when a customer fills out the 'Calculate shipping' form on the cart page (and have one of the postcodes in my shipping method) before being able to proceed to the checkout page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better try with the "Chosen shipping method" from WooCommerce session like:

```
function disable_checkout_button_no_shipping() {

    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

    // remove button if there is no chosen shipping method
    if( empty( $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'disable_checkout_button_no_shipping', 1 );
```

Or in a different way using `woocommerce_check_cart_items` action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'required_chosen_shipping_methods' );
function required_chosen_shipping_methods() {
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

    if( is_array( $chosen_shipping_methods ) && count( $chosen_shipping_methods ) > 0 ) {
        // Display an error message
        wc_add_notice( __("A shipping method is required in order to proceed to checkout."), 'error' );
    }
}
```

It should better work.

Comment: Looks perfect, have tried it on firefox and it seems to work ok there, Will try incognotio mode on chrome next.
Many thanks for that.

Comment: I know this is quite old but shouldn't it be `!is_array() || count(...) == 0` as we want to display the error only in case NO shipping method was selected?

Answer (score 0):

The code above didn't work ($chosen_shipping_methods is an array and if it has more than 0 elements this condition will always be true because $chosen_shipping_methods is an array that is initialized with a default value of array('') in WooCommerce), so I rejigged it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'required_chosen_shipping_methods' );
function required_chosen_shipping_methods() {
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

    // Check if $chosen_shipping_methods is an array and if it contains a valid shipping method
    if( is_array( $chosen_shipping_methods ) && ! in_array( '', $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
        // A valid shipping method has been selected, so do nothing
        return;
    }

    // Display an error message
    wc_add_notice( __("A shipping method is required in order to proceed to checkout."), 'error' );
}
```