# force the user to calculate the shipment or select a method before going to the checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my store I would like to be able to force users to use the shipping calculator or to select a shipping method before going to the checkout page.

My slightly modified code removes the default submit method, but it is not a user-force function.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', '__return_false', 99);
```

I appreciate you can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent access to checkout without shipping method in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065801/prevent-access-to-checkout-without-shipping-method-in-woocommerce)

Comment: I already tried the 2 functions that they indicate in the answers, and they do not work.